# Create daily indices in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-indices

I would like to create daily elastic indices. I went through index template in elastic. However, those settings and mappings can be applied only to the new indices. In my case I need a daily index based on certain pattern. How to go?

Comment: If this is for logging use case, you can use logstash which by default creates a new index everyday.

Comment: The index field in elasticsearch output plugin is a string. It is constructed as any other string. You can use the record fields as in any other case. You look that up, you got the answer.

Answer (score 2):

using logstash you can create index with timestamps(for daily)

```
elasticsearch {
                hosts => [ "xxxxx:9200" ]
                index => "Test-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
            }
```